# Keras : order in which dimensions of an input tensor is specified

Tags: keras, keras-layer

Consider an input layer in keras as:

```
 model.add(layers.Dense(32, input_shape=(784,)))
```

What this says is input is a 2D tensor where axix=0 (batch dimension) is not specified while axis=1 is 784. Axis=0 can take any value.

My question is: ***isnt this style confusing?***

Ideally, should it not be

```
 input_shape=(?,784)
```

This reflects axis=0 is wildcard while axis=1 should be 784

**Any particular reason why it is so ? Am I missing something here ?**

Answer (score 0):

The consistency in this case is between the sizes of the layers and the size of the input. In general, the shapes are assumed to represent the nature of the data; in that sense, the batch dimension is not part of the data itself, but rather how you group it for training or evaluation. So, in your code snippet, it is quite clear that you have inputs with 784 features and a first layer producing a vector of 32 features. If you want to explicitly include the batch dimension, you can use instead `batch_input_shape=(None, 784)` (this is sometimes necessary, for example if you want to give batches of a fixed size but with an additional time dimension of unknown size). This is explained in the [`Sequential` model guide](https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/#specifying-the-input-shape), but also matches the documentation of the [`Input`](https://keras.io/layers/core/#input) layer, where you can give a `shape` or `batch_shape` parameter (analogous to `input_shape` or `batch_input_shape`).